# Show that the intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, $(a,b)$ and $(a,\infty)$, are equivalent.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Show that the intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, $(a,b)$ and $(a,\infty)$ are equivalent.

I have had difficulty finding a bijective function between these intervals. Any recommendations?

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{(b-a)a}{x-a}$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that $f(x) = 1/x$ maps $(0,1)$ to $(1,\infty)$.
Can you transform this to do what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Another function besides reciprocal that can help in these situations is tangent:

$$f(x)=\tan\left(\dfrac{(x-a)}{(b-a)}\cdot\dfrac\pi2\right)+a.$$

Comment: Nice!  Also a sigmoid function (going the other direction).

Answer (score 1):

With $a<b$, the function $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{b-a}{b-x} + a -1$ maps $(a,b)$ to $(a,\infty)$.